# How do I return a unicode string / wstring / CStringW from a C++ dll to InstallScript?

Tags: c++, string, dll, installshield, installscript

I am using InstallShield 2013 Premium.  I created a C++ dll in Visual Studio 2010 to provide some functionality I could not achieve with InstallScript alone.  My C++ function needs to return a small string (a username) to the InstallScript after doing considerable work to get this value.

Throughout the C++ am I using CStringW to represent my strings.  Ideally, I would like to return it as Unicode, but I'm content with ANSI if that's my only option.  I have tried numerous approaches with CStringW, std::wstring, std::string, LPCTSTR, LPSTR, char *... I tried direct returns, and attempts to return by reference.  Nothing works!

Sometimes the dll function hangs, sometimes it throws an exception, at best it returns garbage values with non-printing characters.  The official documentation on this does not seem accurate (it doesn't work for me!). Extensive Googling, and searching the Flexera boards produce "solutions" from others struggling with the same ridiculous problem, and yet non of those work for me either...

I didn't try this until the end, as I took for granted that you could pass strings between dlls and InstallScript easily enough.  In retrospect, I should have started with the interface between the two and then developed the dll functionality after that.

Comment: Calling convention of your function is stdcall?

Comment: You could start by creating a dummy app that makes use of your `.dll` function. Also make sure that your `.dll` respects the conventions that InstallShield imposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys!  I finally figured this out for myself though.  There are multiple facets to the solution, however, which I have not found documented or suggested elsewhere.

Major points

1) return a WCHAR * from C++

2) use WSTRING as the corresponding return type in the InstallScript prototype

3) return it into a regular STRING variable in InstallScript, and treat it like any other

4) retain the value the WCHAR * points to in the C++ dll in a static variable, otherwise it apparently gets deleted and the pointer becomes invalid

If you've gotten far enough to find yourself in the same boat, I probably don't need to serve up every detail, but here's a chunk of example code to help you along:

---

Visual Studio Def File

```
LIBRARY MyIsDllHelper
EXPORTS   
   getSomeStringW   @1
```

---

C++ Header

```
#ifdef MYISDLLHELPER_EXPORTS
#define MYISDLLHELPER_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYISDLLHELPER_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include <stdexcept>
#include <atlstr.h>

namespace MyIsDllHelper
{
    class MyIsDllHelper
    {
    public:         
    static MYISDLLHELPER_API WCHAR * getSomeStringW();
    };
}
```

---

C++ Source

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyIsDllHelper.h"

static CStringW someStringRetained;

CStringW getTheString()
{
    CStringW s;
    // do whatever...

    return s;
} 

WCHAR * MyIsDllHelper::MyIsDllHelper::getSomeStringW()
{   
    someStringRetained = getTheString();
    return someStringRetained.GetBuffer( someStringRetained.GetLength() ) + L'\0';
}
```

---

InstallScript

```
#define HELPER_DLL_FILE_NAME "MyIsDllHelper.dll"
prototype WSTRING MyIsDllHelper.getSomeStringW();

function DoSomething( hMSI )
    STRING svSomeString;    
    STRING svDllPath;   
begin

    // Find the .dll file path. (A custom function)
    GetSupportFilePath( HELPER_DLL_FILE_NAME, TRUE, svDllPath );    

    // Load the .dll file into memory.
    if( UseDLL( svDllPath ) != 0 ) then
        MessageBox ("Could not load dll: " + svDllPath, SEVERE );
        abort;
    endif;

    // Get the string from the dll 
    try         
        svSomeString = MyIsDllHelper.getSomeStringW();
    catch   
        MessageBox( "Could not execute dll function: MyIsDllHelper.getSomeStringW", SEVERE );
        abort;      
    endcatch;       

    // Remove the .dll file from memory.
    if( UnUseDLL( svDllPath ) < 0 ) then
        MessageBox ("Could not unload dll: " + svDllPath, SEVERE );
        abort;
    endif;

    // Use the string
    MessageBox( "svSomeString: [" + svSomeString + "]", INFORMATION );       

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're best off when you can make your interface use C approaches rather than C++ ones. Match the interface of functions like [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188.aspx) in which your function accepts a pointer to a buffer (and for correctness a size of that buffer), and then writes into that buffer. The majority of your implementation shouldn't have to change, as long as you can finish with something like a [StringCchCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647527.aspx) from your CString into the buffer.

Since you specifically mention CStringW and other Unicode string types, I'd suggest choosing `LPWSTR` (rather than `LPTSTR`) for the interface type.

Then all that's left is declaring this for consumption by InstallScript. This means the prototype should use [WSTRING](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefData_types.htm) and [BYREF](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefBYREF_operator.htm). If the function interface is the same as GetEnvironmentVariableW, the prototype should look something like this:

```
prototype MyFunc(WSTRING, BYREF WSTRING, NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings, but I guess the problem is with the encoding.

Have a look here: https://adventuresinscm.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/unicode-files-and-installshield/

Comment: What type would you return that into on the InstallShield side? (Both prototype and actual string that you want to manipulate and combine with other IS strings?)